# Class inheritance with vector of parents having plural child elements

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm trying to build a gamengine, and I need to sort characters and rooftiles based on the y-coordinate of their feet before drawing them, so that folk/tiles infront are drawn ontop of folk/tiles behind them. I've gotten it to work with just characters, but I need rooftiles as well.

the classes are both children of renderable, and share some data. The classes are forward-declared, and there are global lists g_entities, g_tiles, and g_renderable.

```
class renderable {
public:
    float x;
    float y;
    float width;
    float height;
    SDL_Surface* image;
    SDL_Texture* texture;
    

    void render(SDL_Renderer * renderer, camera fcamera) {
        rect obj(floor((x -fcamera.x)* fcamera.zoom), floor((y-fcamera.y)* fcamera.zoom), floor(width *fcamera.zoom), floor(height * fcamera.zoom));
        rect cam(0, 0, fcamera.width, fcamera.height);

        if(RectOverlap(obj, cam)) {
            SDL_Rect dstrect = { (x -fcamera.x)* fcamera.zoom, (y-fcamera.y)* fcamera.zoom, width *fcamera.zoom, height * fcamera.zoom};
            SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, &dstrect);
        }
    }

};

class entity: public renderable {
public:
    float x;
    float y;
    float xagil;
    float yagil;

    //... other stuff, including image and texture

    void render(SDL_Renderer * renderer, camera fcamera);
};

class tile: public renderable {
public:
    int x;
    int y;
    int z = 0; //represents layer. 0 default

    float width;
    float height;
    
    //... other stuff, including image and texture

    void render(SDL_Renderer * renderer, camera fcamera);

};
```

The list is created when the map is loaded with

```
for (int i = 0; i < g_entities.size(); i++) {
    g_renderable.push_back(g_entities[i]);
}
for (int i = 0; i < g_tiles.size(); i++) {
    if(g_tiles[i]->z ==2) {
        g_renderable.push_back(g_tiles[i]);
        g_tiles.erase(g_tiles.begin() + i);
        i--;
    }
}
```

And then in main I planned to sort the g_renderable array instead of the g_entities array and have everything snug, but instead I get a SIGFAULT. I tracked down the problem with GDB and it turns out that g_renderable[] isnt getting informed with the attributes of g_entities[] (and probly not g_tiles[] either).

This is what I mean:

```
    g_renderable.clear();
    g_renderable.reserve(g_entities.size() + g_tiles.size()); // preallocate memory
    cout << "g_entities.size" <<g_entities.size() << endl;
    cout << "g_entities.size" <<g_entities.size() << endl;
    cout << "g_entities height " << g_entities[0]->height << endl;    //couts 122
    for (int i = 0; i < g_entities.size(); i++) {
        g_renderable.push_back(g_entities[i]);
    }
    cout << "g_renderable height " << g_renderable[0]->height << endl;   //couts 0
    for (int i = 0; i < g_tiles.size(); i++) {
        if(g_tiles[i]->z ==2) {
            g_renderable.push_back(g_tiles[i]);
            g_tiles.erase(g_tiles.begin() + i);
            i--;
        }
    }
```

Why doesnt my vector return the member data as expected?

Comment: Doesn't the book or tutorial you read,  or class you attend, mention *virtual* functions? Or that you need references or *pointers* for polymorphism to work in C++?

Comment: Yes. To be more clear, the three are initialized as 
`vector<entity*> g_entities;
vector<tile*> g_tiles;
vector<renderable*> g_renderable;`
As for virtual, I haven't gotten there yet because its useless until I can successfully transfer the memberdata.

Watch your tone. We're all just chuckleheads here.

Comment: Without virtual functions you are kind of forced to use several vectors, one for each type that can be rendered. With virtual functions all you need is one vector `std::ector<renderable*> g_renderable`, and the correct `render` function will be called no matter the actual type of renderable object stored in the vector.